# Removing item from in-app-purchase [Cleared For Sale = NO] still appears in app

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm doing testing on IAP and was trying to test the scenario whereby I have a list of items for sale. eg:

in the App (V1)

```
public static let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = [
    coins.coins100,
    coins.coins200,
    coins.coins300
]
```

I also have this same set of productIdentifiers set up in AppStoreConnect.

Now lets say, 1 month later I decide to pull 1 of the IAP from sale. Let's call it version 2

in App (V2)

```
public static let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = [
    // coins.coins100,
    coins.coins200,
    coins.coins300
]
```

and within AppStoreConnect I deselect the "Cleared for Sale"
[image]

Now during testing.

For Version 2, where I only have `200coins` and `300coins` in the app being sent to Apple, there's no issue, I end up with the expected 2 products returned for IAP.

But what about version 1 apps? When I tried it, seems like all 3 products is still returned from Apple. (note: Cleared for sale is removed)

The users on version 1 seems to *still* be able to purchase the `100coins` IAP? Is this expected behaviour?

Note : This is a consumable product if it matters.

> Cleared for Sale
>
> Indicates whether your In-App Purchase is cleared for sale or not. If
> this box is unchecked, your In-App Purchase will not be available for
> purchase from within the app. Note that if you set Cleared for Sale to
> No, all settings for the In-App Purchase will still be available to
> edit in iTunes Connect, and you can change Cleared for Sale to Yes at
> a later date.

Answer (score 1):

No in version1 there should be only 2 IAP's because if you uncheck **Cleared for Sale** option under Availability it means that you don't want to let the user purchase this offer.

However, if you are testing in debug mode in the Sandbox environment then I might return 3 products just because three are listed in your app store connect account [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40166588/6737277).

you can submit IAP for review so that apple review can check metadata by Unchecking **Cleared for Sale**. even if your metadata is approved by the Apple review team and IAP status is ready still you can't see this IAP in the list when you are testing in release mode. It will only be available when you check Cleared for sale option.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So basically I can see it now because I am running it in "Debug mode in sandbox environment". If I run it in ```release``` mode it would not appear? I need to test this. Thanks

Comment: yes in realese mode it shuldn't appear

Comment: check in release mode if works please accept answer. it might help others looking for same answer

Comment: Yes. I plan on doing that when I get the chance as well as when I actually submit to apple. TQ for the help.

Comment: Just checked in Release Mode and w/ cleared for sale unchecked, V1 is still able to get access to the IAP. Am I doing something wrong? Note that this app is still in development and 'I'm basically doing testing only. It's not release and app is essentially never been released on the App Store, not sure if this matters